# javascript array with objects length is 0

Tags: javascript, arrays

I implemented the code from this answer: [javascript group by in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110226/javascript-group-by-in-array/40110584#40110584)

I changed the code a little bit so there are more productdetails in the array:

```
   var mapByShop = function(arr, groupName) {
        return arr.reduce(function(result, item) {
        result[item[groupName]] = result[item[groupName]] || [];
        result[item[groupName]][item["productId"]] = item;
            return result;
        }, {});
    };
    console.log("Response", response.data);

    $scope.productList = mapByShop(response.data, "shopName");
    console.log("productList", $scope.productList);
```

The code works fine, it creates an array with shopnames with objects with article objects. For example, the array looks like:

```
Shopname 1:Array[0]
    57ab0360741496001e37586c:Object
        image:"http://pathtoimage.nl/image.jpg"
        name:"Product Name"
        price:32.23
        productId:"57ab0360741496001e37586c"
        productNumber:"ProductNumer 123"
        quantity:1
        shopId:"56699123a9c7a38740a31251"
        shopName:"Shopname 1"
    57ab0360741496001e375867:Object
        {same properties as object above}

Shopname 2:Array[0]
    57bc15ad732b2de02145fe8e:Object
        {same properties as object above}
    57bc15ad732b2de02145fe8f:Object
        {same properties as object above}
    57bc15ad732b2de02145fe90:Object
        {same properties as object above}
    57d157d10b90631c31466329:Object
        {same properties as object above}
    57d158fe0b90631c31466331:Object
        {same properties as object above}
```

As you can see, after the `Shopnames`, there is a notation (copied from console in Chrome) which says `Array[0]`. I want to show the content of this array with a angular `ng-repeat`, but that is not working also.

How can I fix this? I'm pretty new with javascript, so an example would be fine.

Comment: Array[0] means array with no values in it ..similar to   var b = new Array();

console.log(b) ==> Array[0]

Comment: `result[item[groupName]] = result[item[groupName]] || [];
        result[item[groupName]][item["productId"]] = item;` - you're misusing arrays, or misunderstanding them ... either push to the array, or use {} instead of [] to make an object, then forget arrays

Comment: Yeah, {} was the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this, using {}.

```
var mapByShop = function(arr, groupName) {
                    return arr.reduce(function(result, item) {
                    result[item[groupName]] = result[item[groupName]] || {};
                    result[item[groupName]][item["productId"]] = item;
                        return result;
                    }, {});
            };
```